# Checkout Page Dropdown Box Aligning Text Issue Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Dear stackoverflowers,

Somehow the text in the dropboxes of the checkout page are not aligned in the middle. Website https://www.narwal.shop/checkout/

[Link to image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfKKS.png)

Does someone how I can fix this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change line-height to 10px of below CSS:

```
.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

in this file: 
https://www.narwal.shop/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/css/admin.css?ver=3.3.5

Or you can create custom.css file and put above css in that file, do not forgot to include that custom.css file in that page.